# The first plot of my plotly subplot takes up the entire figure (2x4 axis grids)

Tags: python, dimensions, plotly, subplot

I am struggling with something and I can't find a reasonable explanation even though I'm certain it's something small that I've overlooked.

While trying to plot a 2x4 subplot in plotly, the first of the 8 graphs is plotted over the entire 8 grids, rather than being in position (1,1) of the subplot. The remaining 7 graphs are plotted as expected, with the first plot partially visible underneith them. This is the code I am using:

```
#make a new trace (plot) for every sample:
def make_trace(x_list, y_list, samplename):
    trace = go.Scatter(
        x = x_list,
        y = y_list,
        name=samplename
     )

    layout = go.Layout(
        title=samplename,   
        showlegend=True
        )
    )

    return trace, layout

#call the make_trace function for every sample and append to the figure
def make_subplot():

    fig = tls.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=4,plot_titles=cols_list)
    row_num = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
    column_num = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
    i = 0

    for sample in cols_list[1:]:
        trace, layout = make_trace(normalised_df['percentage'],                                                     
                                   normalised_df[sample], sample)            
        fig.append_trace(trace, row_num[i], column_num[i])
        i += 1

    fig['layout'].update(title='Normalized Mean Coverage', height=600,   
                        width=800,showlegend=False,font=dict(size=14),     
                        xaxis=dict(title="Transcript Length (%)"),                          
                        yaxis=dict(title="Normalised Mean Coverage"))
    iplot(fig)

#call the function to create the entire figure:
make_subplot()
```

The output looks like this:
[coverage plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWCOq.png)

**Last words: The solution seems to lie somewhere in setting the xaxis/yaxis titles... When I change them in 'layout' in the function call rather than calling fig.update() afterwards the subplot works as expected but its just way too small. The problem is that I want to keep `make_trace()` as a separate function, as I call it later for a combined plot, so I can't change its x/yaxis titles in this function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the xaxis and yaxis titles for each subplot individually:

```
for idx, sample in enumerate(cols_list):
    trace, layout = make_trace(normalised_df['percentage'],                               
                               normalised_df[sample], sample) 
    fig.append_trace(trace, row_num[i], column_num[i])
    fig['layout']['xaxis{}'.format(idx+1)].update(title='Transcript Length (%)')
    fig['layout']['yaxis{}'.format(idx+1)].update(title='Normalised Mean Coverage')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems that this was a bug in the plotly library. It has been solved in my case by updating the plotly package to 3.6.0 for R. In Python I do not know if this is also a bug. But if so just do a bug report in github.

Best regards
Sinan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting axis and axis anchors for each of the subplots? Such as this:

```
t1 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1(x), xaxis="x1", yaxis="y1", name="Trace 1")
t2 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2(x), xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2", name="Trace 2")

layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis1=dict(anchor="y1", domain=[0, 1]),
    yaxis1=dict(anchor="x1", domain=[0.25, 0.45]),

    xaxis2=dict(anchor="y2", domain=[0.5, 1]),
    yaxis2=dict(anchor="x2", domain=[0.8, 1]))
```